# Optimal way to setup UIView in UIViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I'm wondering if my method to setup my UIViewController is optimal or just plain stupid.

I have typedef'ed an enum with some categories. Let's say 6 different categories.
So depending on which category is the selected one. My UIViewController have a switch which will call different method to setup my UIView according to the selected category.

Just wondering if this is a good method to do this, or should I consider creating 6 different UIViewControllers?

A discussion with pro and cons is very much appreciated.

Thanks.

They are basically the same.

Sample code:

```
switch (self.category) {
    case vegetables:
        recipe = [[[WebServices sharedInstance].recipeDictionary objectForKey:self.chosenCategory] objectAtIndex:4]; //Needs to be made random
        descriptionText.text = recipe.recipeDescription;
        [self setupText];
        [self setupVegetablesView];
        break;
    case dairy:
        recipe = [[[WebServices sharedInstance].recipeDictionary objectForKey:self.chosenCategory] objectAtIndex:4]; //Needs to be made random
        descriptionText.text = recipe.recipeDescription;
        [self setupText];
        [self setupDairyProductsView];
        break;


- (void)setupVegetablesView
{
    descriptionText.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:103/255.0 blue:55/255.0 alpha:1];

    background.image = imageBackgroundVegetables;
    topBar.image = topBarForVegetables;
    subtitle.image = subtitleImageVegetables;
    subtitleLink.image = subtitleLinkBarVegetables;
...
}
```

Comment: Please post some code on how you modify the uiview depending on the enum

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your situation. If the view controllers are similar, than this makes sense. But if they are completely different from each other, use separate subclasses.

Comment: The UIViews are basically the same except of color changes and text changes. I do all the allocations in viewDidLoad, then change properties depending on chosen category. I'm also wondering if I should use a switch or if, else clause.

Comment: @SinLi use a switch, since if you want to add more views the indentation of the if else if would increase, instead using switch would make it more clear :)

Answer (score 1):

I would implement it as following
• i would several UIView derived class each one for the type of UIView that i need
For example, i would have `VegatableView` and `DiaryView`
• each one of these view will have the same base class of for example `MyBaseView`
• MyBaseView will have a function called `setup` this function will need to be implemented in each of my derived classes (vegetable and diary)
• depending on your enum i would create one of these concrete classes and call the setup function

Example:

```
switch (self.category) {
    MyBaseView recipe;
    case vegetables:
        //Create an instance of VegetableView
        recipe = [[VegetableView alloc] init];
        break;
    case dairy:
        //Create an instance of DiaryView
        recipe = [[VegetableView alloc] init];
        break;
}
//Call setup for the created view
[recipe setup];

//Setup function in vegetableView.m
- (void)setup
{
    //Do some vegetable setup stuff
}

//Setup function in diaryView.m
- (void)setup
{
    //Do some diary setup stuff
}
```

In this way, i would minimize the different code, i would make the parameter equal for both the types of view
Also adding new views will be rather easy, just subclass MyBaseView and implement a setup function that is specialized for your new view
Hence increase the objects decoupling and reducing complexity

Comment: That is basically what I do :) whatever I need to alloc or initialize for the first time, I do it in my UIViewController viewDidLoad, and other setup or changes, I do it in my - (void)setup :).

Comment: Yes but from the code i saw you posted is that the setup function is inside the viewcontroller it self, what am suggesting is to move it in the view classes them selves. so instead of [self setupText] and [self setupSomeThing]; you would call [view setup];

Comment: Oh yeah, that is a good suggestion actually. I can see that now :)